# Call one bash script through another bash script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Let's say below .bash exist in a directory:

```
tellus@proetl01:~/Prod/Jcs/BIN/Dash_PPLP/load$ ls -ltr
total 29
drwxrwxr-x   2 tellus   tellus         4 Sep  7 11:32 archive
drwxrwxr-x   2 tellus   tellus        20 Sep  7 11:33 test
-rwxrwxr-x   1 tellus   tellus       219 Sep  7 14:56 transform_to_load.bash
-rwxrwxr-x   1 tellus   tellus       169 Sep  7 15:00 final_transform.bash
```

I want to call final_transform.bash through transform_to_load.bash (at the end of it)

How is this possible?

Please assist :)

Thank you very much

Comment: Do some research about the `source` command (also know as the `.` command). Or, since the scripts are marked as executable (and I assume they have a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))) then why not simply run it as a normal program? And *please* tell us what you have tried, and how that worked or didn't work. Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can you just use ``./final_transform.bash`` into ``transform_to_load.bash`` ?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? `final_transform.bash` is a command like any other you might be running in `transform_to_load.bash`. The only question is what inputs does `final_transform.bash` require that `transform_to_load.bash` might be providing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add Either

```
./final_transform.bash
```

or

```
bash final_transform.bash
```

at the end of `transform_to_load.bash` file should work.